# In App Dynamics calculating the sum of a transaction metric

Tags: appdynamics

I am creating a dashboard in App Dynamics and would like to get the sum of the metric calls/minute for an endpoint of my web service.
How can I do that?
I can create the graph of calls/minute for a day.
[image]

But I would like to display the sum of these calls for a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to display the total number of calls for a Business Transaction over a 24 hour period:

- (Load Dashbord in Edit Mode)
- Click "Add Widget"
- Click "Metric Value"
- Click "Select a Metric"
- Specify the Application and BT in top 2 sections
- In next section click "Select a Metric"
- Click "Calls per Minute" / "Select Metric"
- Change "Value" to "Sum" in dropdown
- Click "Save"
- (optional) For time range can fix this to 24 hours by using the "Use Widget-Specific Time Range" option in the main widget edit screen (otherwise the dashboard time range will be used for the widget)
- Click "Save"

(Docs for Dashboard widgets are here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Widgets)